# SQL access to an XL device using HTTP Post vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, http-post

I am currently working on a project that is supposed to pull data from an XL device to a central location. I emailed the company and they said I need to make an HTTP POST request and parse the returned JSON. Additionally they said that i should make my post request in this format.

```
POST /sql-request.do HTTP/1.0
Content-Length: 141
response_type=application/json&sql_statement=select sequence_number, 
start_time
from timeline_stream order by sequence_number desc limit 5;
```

I have put what i believe to be this code into vb.net, and I get a response from the server. However it is not the requested table information. Here is the code I am currently using.

```
Private Sub webRequester()

    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
    Dim replyStreamReader As StreamReader = Nothing
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp("http://192.168.100.223/data/schema/expanded?response_type=application%2Fjson&sql_statement=select%20*%20from%20Intervals")
    Dim postData As String = "test"
    Dim data() As Byte = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)

    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("User", "Pass")
    request.ContentLength = data.Length
    request.Method = "POST"
    Using requestStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream
        requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
    End Using

    response = request.GetResponse()
    replyStreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream)
    Dim responseFromServer As String = replyStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
    Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer)
End Sub
```

I have also tried using the query string as my postData, but it still returns what seems to be some default response. It is 78 pages when put in word, so here is the first line of the response I am getting.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><data_schema><registers><table name="extended_user_strings" number="8" min_rows="1" max_rows="1" defined_by="system" display_name="extended_user_strings_literal" help_text="table_extended_user_strings_copy"><column name="string_1" number="1" index="no" display_name="extended_user_string_1_literal" help_text="extended_user_string_copy" type="string" access="read_write"><restrictions><max_length value="1024" /><pattern value="^[\x20-\xFE]*$" /></restrictions></column><column name="string_10" number="10" index="no" display_name="extended_user_string_10_literal" help_text="extended_user_string_copy" type="string" access="read_write"><restrictions><max_length value="1024"
```

How can I query the device and get the table I'm looking for?

Comment: You are sending the parameters (`response_type=application%2Fjson&sql_statement=select%20*%20from%20Intervals`) in the query string instead of the body of the post request.  Try setting `postData` to that value, instead of "test", and removing it (and the question mark) from the URL.

Comment: I have tried that and i still get the long string of nonsense @Mark